# Как исправить ошибку с gulp (Ошибка JS)?

Tags: javascript, node.js, gulp, npm

```
$ gulp
[13:47:09] Using gulpfile D:\gulpWeb\gulpfile.js
[13:47:09] Starting 'default'...
[13:47:09] Starting 'watchFiles'...
[13:47:09] Starting 'serve'...
[13:47:09] Starting 'clean'...
[13:47:09] Finished 'clean' after 50 ms
[13:47:09] Starting 'html'...
[13:47:09] Starting 'css'...
[13:47:09] Starting 'js'...
[13:47:09] Starting 'images'...
[13:47:09] Starting 'fonts'...
[13:47:10] Finished 'fonts' after 345 ms
[Browsersync] Access URLs:
 --------------------------------------
       Local: http://localhost:3000
    External: http://192.168.0.107:3000
 --------------------------------------
          UI: http://localhost:3001
 UI External: http://localhost:3001
 --------------------------------------
[Browsersync] Serving files from: ./dist/
[13:47:10] gulp-notify: [JS Error] Error: Received a non-Vinyl object in `dest()`
[13:47:10] Finished 'js' after 605 ms
[Browsersync] 1 file changed (index.html)
[13:47:10] Finished 'html' after 746 ms
[Browsersync] 1 file changed (style.min.css)
[13:47:10] Finished 'css' after 1.03 s
[Browsersync] Reloading Browsers... (buffered 2 events)
[13:47:12] gulp-imagemin: Minified 1 image (saved 44.2 kB - 69.1%)
[Browsersync] 1 file changed (2.png)
[13:47:12] Finished 'images' after 2.55 s
```

```
{
    "name": "gulp-web",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "description": "project using gulp4",
    "author": "Kirill",
    "devDependencies": {
        "@babel/core": "^7.15.0",
        "@babel/preset-env": "^7.15.0",
        "babel-core": "^6.26.3",
        "babel-loader": "^8.2.2",
        "babel-preset-env": "^1.7.0",
        "browser-sync": "^2.27.5",
        "del": "^6.0.0",
        "gulp": "^4.0.2",
        "gulp-autoprefixer": "^8.0.0",
        "gulp-babel": "^8.0.0",
        "gulp-cssbeautify": "^3.0.0",
        "gulp-cssnano": "^2.1.3",
        "gulp-imagemin": "^7.1.0",
        "gulp-notify": "^4.0.0",
        "gulp-plumber": "^1.2.1",
        "gulp-rename": "^2.0.0",
        "gulp-sass": "^5.0.0",
        "gulp-strip-css-comments": "^2.0.0",
        "gulp-uglify": "^3.0.2",
        "panini": "^1.7.2",
        "rigger": "^1.0.1",
        "vinyl": "^2.2.1",
        "webpack": "^5.51.1",
        "webpack-stream": "^6.1.2"
    },
    "browserslist": [
        "last 1 version",
        "> 1%",
        "IE 10"
    ],
    "dependencies": {
        "sass": "^1.38.1"
    }
}
```

```
"use strict";

const {src, dest} = require("gulp");
const gulp = require("gulp");
const autoprefixer = require("gulp-autoprefixer");
const cssbeautify = require("gulp-cssbeautify");
const removeComments = require('gulp-strip-css-comments');
const rename = require("gulp-rename");
const sass = require("gulp-sass")(require('sass'));
const cssnano = require("gulp-cssnano");
const uglify = require("gulp-uglify");
const plumber = require("gulp-plumber");
const rigger = require("rigger");
/* const panini = require("panini"); */
const imagemin = require("gulp-imagemin");
const del = require("del");
const notify = require("gulp-notify");
/* const webpack = require('webpack');
const webpackStream = require('webpack-stream'); */
const browserSync = require("browser-sync").create();




/* Paths */
const srcPath = 'src/';
const distPath = 'dist/';

const path = {
    build: {
        html:   distPath,
        js:     distPath + "assets/js/",
        css:    distPath + "assets/css/",
        images: distPath + "assets/img/",
        fonts:  distPath + "assets/fonts/"
    },
    src: {
        html:   srcPath + "*.html",
        js:     srcPath + "assets/js/*.js",
        css:    srcPath + "assets/sass/*.scss",
        images: srcPath + "assets/img/**/*.{jpg,png,svg,gif,ico,webp,webmanifest,xml,json}",
        fonts:  srcPath + "assets/fonts/**/*.{eot,woff,woff2,ttf,svg}"
    },
    watch: {
        html:   srcPath + "**/*.html",
        js:     srcPath + "assets/js/**/*.js",
        css:    srcPath + "assets/sass/**/*.scss",
        images: srcPath + "assets/img/**/*.{jpg,png,svg,gif,ico,webp,webmanifest,xml,json}",
        fonts:  srcPath + "assets/fonts/**/*.{eot,woff,woff2,ttf,svg}"
    },
    clean: "./" + distPath
}



/* Tasks */

function serve() {
    browserSync.init({
        server: {
            baseDir: "./" + distPath
        }
    });
}

function html() {
    /* panini.refresh(); */
    return src(path.src.html, {base: srcPath})
        .pipe(plumber())
        /* .pipe(panini({
            root:       srcPath,
            layouts:    srcPath + 'layouts/',
            partials:   srcPath + 'partials/',
            helpers:    srcPath + 'helpers/',
            data:       srcPath + 'data/'
        })) */
        .pipe(dest(path.build.html))
        .pipe(browserSync.reload({stream: true}));
}

function css() {
    return src(path.src.css, {base: srcPath + "assets/sass/"})
        .pipe(plumber({
            errorHandler : function(err) {
                notify.onError({
                    title:    "SCSS Error",
                    message:  "Error: <%= error.message %>"
                })(err);
                this.emit('end');
            }
        }))
        .pipe(sass({
            includePaths: './node_modules/'
        }))
        .pipe(autoprefixer({
            cascade: true
        }))
        .pipe(cssbeautify())
        .pipe(dest(path.build.css))
        .pipe(cssnano({
            zindex: false,
            discardComments: {
                removeAll: true
            }
        }))
        .pipe(removeComments())
        .pipe(rename({
            suffix: ".min",
            extname: ".css"
        }))
        .pipe(dest(path.build.css))
        .pipe(browserSync.reload({stream: true}));
}

function cssWatch() {
    return src(path.src.css, {base: srcPath + "assets/sass/"})
        .pipe(plumber({
            errorHandler : function(err) {
                notify.onError({
                    title:    "SCSS Error",
                    message:  "Error: <%= error.message %>"
                })(err);
                this.emit('end');
            }
        }))
        .pipe(sass({
            includePaths: './node_modules/'
        }))
        .pipe(rename({
            suffix: ".min",
            extname: ".css"
        }))
        .pipe(dest(path.build.css))
        .pipe(browserSync.reload({stream: true}));
}

function js() {
    return src(path.src.js, {base: srcPath + 'assets/js/'})
        .pipe(plumber({
            errorHandler : function(err) {
                notify.onError({
                    title:    "JS Error",
                    message:  "Error: <%= error.message %>"
                })(err);
                this.emit('end');
            }
        }))
        .pipe(rigger())
        .pipe(dest(path.build.js))
        .pipe(uglify())
        .pipe(rename({
            suffix: ".min",
            extname: ".js"
        }))
        .pipe(dest(path.build.js))
        .pipe(browserSync.reload({stream: true}));
}

function jsWatch() {
    return src(path.src.js, {base: srcPath + 'assets/js/'})
        .pipe(plumber({
            errorHandler : function(err) {
                notify.onError({
                    title:    "JS Error",
                    message:  "Error: <%= error.message %>"
                })(err);
                this.emit('end');
            }
        }))
        .pipe(dest(path.build.js))
        .pipe(browserSync.reload({stream: true}));
}

function images() {
    return src(path.src.images)
        .pipe(imagemin([
            imagemin.gifsicle({interlaced: true}),
            imagemin.mozjpeg({quality: 95, progressive: true}),
            imagemin.optipng({optimizationLevel: 5}),
            imagemin.svgo({
                plugins: [
                    { removeViewBox: true },
                    { cleanupIDs: false }
                ]
            })
        ]))
        .pipe(dest(path.build.images))
        .pipe(browserSync.reload({stream: true}));
}

function fonts() {
    return src(path.src.fonts)
        .pipe(dest(path.build.fonts))
        .pipe(browserSync.reload({stream: true}));
}

function clean() {
    return del(path.clean);
}

function watchFiles() {
    gulp.watch([path.watch.html], html);
    gulp.watch([path.watch.css], cssWatch);
    gulp.watch([path.watch.js], jsWatch);
    gulp.watch([path.watch.images], images);
    gulp.watch([path.watch.fonts], fonts);
}

const build = gulp.series(clean, gulp.parallel(html, css, js, images, fonts));
const watch = gulp.parallel(build, watchFiles, serve);



/* Exports Tasks */
exports.html = html;
exports.css = css;
exports.js = js;
exports.images = images;
exports.fonts = fonts;
exports.clean = clean;
exports.build = build;
exports.watch = watch;
exports.default = watch;
```

Comment: `.pipe(dest(path.build.html))` похоже вы сюда в `dest` передаете что-то не правильное

Comment: на английском стаке просто советуют обновить vynil

Comment: ошибка была при использовании плагина rigger